# Is it possible to extract and re-use the API of a mobile banking app

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

I am aware of the basic techniques used to reverse engineer and extract meaningful information in order to re-use an applications API.

I am not fully adept with the advanced techniques however.

Is it reasonably possible to extract the API information in order to re-use it. In general I ask as I am aware all apps are created differently.

I'm thinking the biggest problem would be if there is any advanced obfuscation of code.

That said, is it possible that reading code isn't required. If I could just MITM the SSL connection then I could figure out the API. I would need to change the SSL cert in app if exists. This would change the APK signature though.

Comment: Why would you want to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think that is relevant. Isn't this a site about security etc and not the motivations. I'm not black hat I assure you. I'm a mobile developer and because financial/banking should be at the forefront i'm just trying to figure out the security techniques etc.. Also, wouldn't it be handy to have API access to your bank?

Comment: Also, people asking questions often get slated for asking vague unanswerable questions etc Questions get closed, downvoted all the time. I just want it on record that your comment, @JonathanGray adds no value!

Comment: If you're trying to do it for learning purposes, then that's fine. But there are much better ways of learning than reverse engineering something specific. A developer creates new things out of previous knowledge and experience. A big part of that is learning through open source software. No idea why you would want to limit yourself by choosing to learn from something in specific like this. If you know how it works, make your own API. The best way to learn is to just go ahead and try.

Comment: I can only detect a single question here and this is not really specific:  "Is it reasonably possible to extract  ...  In general I ask ..." . Therefore I propose to close as too broad. Since it looks like that you are aware of the basic techniques you might edit the question to be more specific about the problems you have to get better feedback.

Comment: @AndréBorie I find my bank's app to be perfectly fine, it does the job I need it to do. I rely on my bank to hire professionals to secure my transactions, because if my bank messes up they're ultimately responsible for any legal repercussions on my behalf. I wouldn't personally put that kind of trust into another's hands, regardless of any kind of perceived benefits. I wouldn't expect anyone else to either.

Comment: @AndréBorie You might be breaking the terms and conditions of the bank itself by making such an app. Many apps specify in deep in the terms of service that simply by using their application, you agree to such terms and  this usually includes prohibition of reverse engineering with possible punishment by law depending on jurisdiction. Not only that, but if you're planning on having multiple people use your app and it becomes compromised, you are responsible for any legal repercussions unless you make it absolutely clear in your application that people are to use it at their own risk.

Comment: @AndréBorie There are just too many reasons not to do it and not really any legitimate reason to do it, at least without wasted time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MITM is the way to go.

**Reverse-Engineer possible Certificate-Pinning**

You will first have to change the certificate. I assume any reasonable banking app has it pinned.
Create your own certificate and change it. Remove the signature from the APK file so that Android will install it.

**Redirect to your MITM Server**

You will have to redirect requests from the app to your MITM server. You can change the hostname in the app but the easier way is to sniff what servers the app is connecting to and set up your own DNS (can be done with any non-cheap home router or Windows tools).

**Root CA**

If your certificate is not signed by a trusted Android root CA you will have to add the signing certificate to your phones root CAs. I dont know how to do this in particular but Google will help.

**Set up the MITM server**

I'd suggest that your MITM server keeps track of all the traffic, appears to be the simplest way to me. But you could also use a network sniffer (e.g. Wireshark) und decipher the traffic with your own certificate.

If Android installs the App (enable installing from untrusted sources) everthing should work.

Comment: Can one work around certificate pinning by injecting a replacement **libopenssl.so**?

Comment: Depends on how the app is verifying the certificate. One might have to include very much "lying-logic" into that replacement to make the app believe it is using the pinned certificate while it isnt.
Also, i'd consider any SSL connection with that .so insecure.

Comment: *i'd consider any SSL connection with that .so insecure* what do you mean by that? From the POV of the bank? Or of the user of banking app?

Comment: I consider writing/modifying an SSL library non-trivial, errors will sneak in. Therefore, any process using that libssl could compromise confidential data (as intended regarding the banking app).
What i'm trying to say is: before doing that, factory reset the phone, even better, flash it. And dont log into anything except that bank account.

Comment: Sure, one will forge such replacement SSL lib only for reverse-engineering that bank protocol, not as a daily driver.